# Background-image in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I m beginner at jQuery , I have a problem to fix background , the image appears the display in 1 sec

```
<body id="content" style="display: none;background-image:url('images/wood.jpg'); ">
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the display to none therefore after 1 second you'll need to remove this.

You should use the window.setTimeout function. 1000 ms = 1 second.

[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

You can set the visiblity using jQuery like so:

```
$("#content").show();
```

So a complete code example would be:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $("#content").show();
},1000)
```

Comment: 1seconde is a time of loading page , it appears and when a page is loaded it diplay

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. Are you saying the image takes 1 second to load?

Comment: No , it appears one second ( before page is loaded )